# Automatic pop when @Environment in base view changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, environment, viewmodifier

In the `ContentView` we have a modifier set to the NavigationView which checks whether the screen is `.compact` or `.regular`. When we push the `NavigationLink` we go to the next screen. If we start multitasking on iPad (open 2 apps simultaneously) and change our app screen from small to big, we get pop onto the `NavigationLink`. Is there a way to prevent that.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    Button("Dismiss") {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Click me")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Tab 1")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .modifier(DummyModifier(isPresented: $isPresented))
    }
}

struct DummyModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
                content
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                        Text("Sheet")
                    }
            } else {
                content
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                        Text("Fullscreen")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: navigation view is deprecated now,  you should change to navigation stack, as using navigation view can lead to unexpected behaviours.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: @andylee I am targeting iOS 15